# Dir all files to output.log, including message "File Not Found"

Tags: windows-server-2003

I'm trying to dir a bunch of files with dos command: dir

My dir.bat file:

```
dir E:\documentos\57\Asiento\01\"Asiento 3 Modificacion de Estatuto.doc"
dir E:\documentos\134\Asiento\01\"File Does Not Exist.doc"
dir E:\documentos\55\Asiento\01\"Asiento 5 Padron de Afiliados Segunda Entrega.doc"
```

The second one doesn't exist.

Then, when running my bat:

```
C:\myuser>E:\dir.bat > output.log
```

I open output.log and don't find any message about the file that was not found.

Output.log :

```
E:\documentos>dir E:\documentos\57\Asiento\01\"Asiento 3 Modificacion de Estatuto.doc" 
 Volume in drive E is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 0027-F7F6

 Directory of E:\documentos\57\Asiento\01

20/12/2005  06:41 p.m.            40,960 Asiento 3 Modificacion de Estatuto.doc
               1 File(s)         40,960 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  17,053,155,328 bytes free

E:\documentos>dir E:\documentos\134\Asiento\01\"File Does Not Exist.doc" 
 Volume in drive E is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 0027-F7F6

 Directory of E:\documentos\134\Asiento\01


E:\documentos>dir E:\documentos\55\Asiento\01\"Asiento 5 Padron de Afiliados Segunda Entrega.doc" 
 Volume in drive E is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 0027-F7F6

 Directory of E:\documentos\55\Asiento\01

08/08/2007  08:33 a.m.            40,960 Asiento 5 Padron de Afiliados Segunda Entrega.doc
               1 File(s)         40,960 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  17,053,151,232 bytes free
```

---

Is there any way that output.log shows "File Not Found" message?

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer:

```
C:\myuser>E:\dir.bat > output.log 2>&1
```

This will redirect the "File Not Found" message to output.log and not showing on CMD.

Comment: The main reason here being that a "File not found" message from the `dir` command is sent to STDERR, while a simple redirect using `>` only redirects STDOUT - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams for details. Using the `2>&1` notation redirects STRERR (2) into STDOUT which is finally redirected into your log file.